# Localized encoding name in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, localization, character-encoding, globalization

How do I get a localized encoding name in .Net framework version 4.0?

When running on a Japanese computer (regional settings)

this line of code:

```
Encoding.GetEncodings()[0].DisplayName
```

when running in .Net 2, returns the string "IBM EBCDIC (US - カナダ)"

when running in .Net 4, returns the string "IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)"

The current culture is "ja-JP" in both cases.

Comment: I know this line of code doesn't make much sense, and I'm not really interested in the first encoding that returns, this is just to demonstrate the change in behavior between .net 2 and .net 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to guess, the Encoding class doesn't have a *DisplayName* property.  If you actually meant *EncodingName* then, yes, the name you get back is localized and depends on the language pack that's installed on the machine.  Sounds like you have the Japanese language pack installed for .NET 2.0 but not for .NET 4.0.

You can [download it here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3324).  Change the language before you click the download button.

Comment: Thanks you!, It was indeed the language pack that I was missing.
It must have worked in .net 2 because it came with (the japanese) windows and was already localized, while .net 4 was included with my setup.
Now I just need to figure out a way to have this installed in the right language on any computers...

Comment: Don't.  This is only a problem on your machine.  Your Japanese user will of course already have the language pack installed on her machine.

Comment: Actually, since my product installs .net 4 on their computers for the first time in most cases, they don't have the language pack.
My setup will need to include it or I will have to use the web installer to have it installed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The `Encoding.GetEncodings()` is just a list of all available encodings in the system. You shouldn't expect the one at index 0 to be your system default. Use following code to get the encoding corresponding to your current thread culture

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)
```

Or perhaps you want to use `EBCDICCodePage` property to be more consistent with the encodings you've provided. Hard to say without knowing what exactly you need this for.

I suspect what you actually looking for is the current culture

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName
```

and not the encoding, otherwise why wouldn't you just use UTF-8? Or if you are looking for the display name of the "ja-JP" culture specifically, then this should do it

```
new CultureInfo("ja-JP").DisplayName
```

Comment: I'd understand if you were looking for localized name of a culture (which you can get via `NativeName`), but why do you need localized name of an encoding?

Comment: A module in my product displays a list of available encodings and my Japanese costumers used to see that list in japanese before I moved to .net 4, the change is uncomfortable to some of them who do not speak English.